# Is it possible to get RuntimeVisibleAnnotations from JVMTI or JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jvmti

In the [JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) and the [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) documentations I can't find a reference for `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations`. Is it possible (eventually with constant pool) to get the annotations?

Comment: In which form would you like to get these annotations? You can just invoke Java `getDeclaredAnnotations()` method using JNI `CallObjectMethod`.

Comment: @apangin: Thank you for this hint